# How to install H2O driverless-ai on AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, h2o, nvidia-docker

When trying to install driverless-ai on AWS EC2, I execute all the steps until the step 6 in the guide:
"6. Start the Driverless AI docker image:"

I try the command described there:

```
nvidia-docker run --rm -u ‘id -u‘:‘id -g‘ -p 12345:12345 -p 9090:9090 -v ‘pwd‘/data:/data -v ‘pwd‘/log:/log -v ‘pwd‘/license:/license opsh2oai/h2oai-runtime
```

and get back:
unknown shorthand flag: 'g' in -g‘

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really to need to pass the current linux user uid/pid with the -p parameter of "nvidia-docker run" command. This is how u can do it.

If you run id command on a Ubuntu machine you will see the following udi/gid for the logged user name "ubuntu":

```
$ id
uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu)
```

You will be using this info with the -p parameter with "nvidia-docker run" command as below:

```
nvidia-docker run -u 1000:1000
```

What you can do it run the following command to get help on nvidia-docker:

```
nvidia-docker run --help
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong quote.  Your example has an apostrophe (') and it should be a backquote (`).

Backquote (correct):

```
$ echo `id -g`
20
```

Apostrophe (incorrect):

```
$ echo 'id -g'
id -g
```

Also note that the instructions now refer to an AMI-based startup (so you shouldn't have to type this stuff in yourself anymore).